# ASP.NET - nothing causes a 404 ! - what could cause this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6

I've just installed an old ASP.Net app on a new machine. It works except that I've noticed that no url from within the apps virtual directory will cause a 404 to be returned and I can't figure out what would cause this ?

So just to be clear:

```
http://myserver.example.com/myapp/login.aspx
```

returns 200 as it should because login.aspx exists but

```
http://myserver.example.com/myapp/login-no-such-url.aspx
```

returns 200 as well but login-no-such-url.aspx does not exist. The IIS log shows 200 for this url and the browser receives this :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" 
content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>
```

- In case it was causing it I've removed all code from the **Global.asax.cs** / **Application_Error** function.
- Other virtual directories on the same server *do* return 404's.
- 'Custom Errors' in the virtdir properties points at the standard 404b.htm and that file exists and contains the standard 404 text.

Where should I be looking to determine why IIS does not recognise non-existent URL's ?

---

**EDIT1:**
The only thing I can see in the web.config belonging to the virtual directory that seems relevant to this is :

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

It's quite a complex web.config with a lot of application specific entries but I'm pretty sure that's the only relevant thing; however I would be interested to hear of suggestions for things in web.config that might be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the web.config file? There might be some configuration there as to what to do with 404 errors etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've made an edit to the question as I can't format in the comments.